# Hibernate many to one relationship annotated

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

When running the method to get a patient address the hibernate says the table does not exist

For the relationship address to patient;

```
OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Address.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
```

Join column in the address class

```
 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "Patient_Id", nullable = false)
    private Patient patient;
```

When running a query to fetch the patient and then print out many address it says that the table does not exist.
Query to fetch patient

```
 @NamedQuery(
                        name = "findPatientByFullName",
                        query = "select p from Patient p where p.firstName = :firstName AND p.lastName = :lastName"
                )
```

```
System.out.println(sM.getPatientByFullName("Tom", "Test").get(0).getFirstName());
       List<Patient> patients = sM.getPatientByFullName("Tom", "Test");
```

Get Patients by full name method

```
public List<Patient> getPatientByFullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        List patientsName = null;
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            TypedQuery query = session.getNamedQuery("findPatientByFullName");
            query.setParameter("firstName", firstName);
            query.setParameter("lastName", lastName);
            patientsName = query.getResultList();
        }catch (HibernateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }return patientsName;
    }
```

Getting a list of the patients, But then when I want to find a list of the address it errors.

```
Apr 29, 2019 10:58:38 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
Apr 29, 2019 10:58:38 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'KYMb02vi2Z.Patient_PatientEmailAddress' doesn't exist
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:419)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2286)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:581)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:168)
    at SessionManager.main(SessionManager.java:45)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'KYMb02vi2Z.Patient_PatientEmailAddress' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:970)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1020)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 18 more
```

The stack trace error

Answer (score 0):

See the error carefully. It shows you for the `Patient_PatientEmailAddress`,which is not found. so please check again your things in code and tell me. Also check your mapper that what you pass in it.
Thanks

Comment: The table PatientEmailAddress exists on the db, I am wondering why the annotation mapping does not work.

Comment: So.please use @Entity,@Table(name="PatientEmailAddress ").write the same as it exist in database.

Comment: @Entity
@Table(name = "PatientEmailAddress") is already added to my patient email class